# Possible to generate Data with While in List Comprehension

Tags: python

Is it possible to populate a list with list comprehension by just using while statement?

**List Comprehension with for:**

```
r =  [i for i in range(0,5)]
```

> r = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Is it possible to construct that with a while?

**Prototype:**

```
i=0
print [i+=1 while i<5]
```

Comment: Nop, statements are not allowed in a list comprehension. Though checkout [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, "while does not produce a sequence" is a great hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not exactly do what you want in a list comprehension,but since that you want to generate some items while they meet an condition it's better to create an generator from what you want (which produce items on demand) and then filter your generator with `itertools.takewhile`.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x:x<5,range(5))) #in python 2.X pass an Xrange  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: So for range is actually already a very compact form of the statement above. thanks kasramvd

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `yield`. For more complex operations, this can be simpler and more maintainable overall:

```
def generate_less_than(val):
    i = 0
    while i < val:
        yield i
        i += 1

r = list(generate_less_than(5))
```

This also has the benefit of giving you an easily reusable generator, meaning you can allow different portions of the application to decide whether they just need a generator for iteration or they need a `list`. Parameterization is also simple.

Answer (score -1):

You're already on the right track.  This works just fine:

```
print [i for i in range(5)]
```

You might also enjoy the "disposable" variable, the underscore:

```
print [_ for _ in range(5)]
```

This works for list comprehensions and other contexts where the index is not used beyond the scope of the iteration.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "disposable" variable.

Comment: @Ketan, where are you stuck on it?  You *did* search the usage before you posted your comment, right?  You found the SO explanations and the others on the internet, I hope.

Comment: @Ketan The `_` variable is a convention in Python. It's used to indicate, "I do not care about this value and will never use it." It's *usually* used when some function returns a `tuple` and you only care about part of the result, like this: `first_val, _, third_val = func_returns_3_tuple()`. I don't think the convention of that variable applies here, since you *are* using the value in the list comprehension.